# Pack consecutive duplicates of list elements into sublists in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I found this problem in the website *99 problems in ocaml*. After some thinking I solved it by breaking the problem into a few smaller subproblems. Here is my code:

```
let rec frequency x l=
match l with 
|[]-> 0
|h::t-> if x=[h] then 1+(frequency x t)
else frequency x t
;;

let rec expand x n=
match n with
|0->[]
|1-> x
|_-> (expand x (n-1)) @ x
;;


let rec deduct a b=
match b with 
|[]-> []
|h::t -> if a=[h] then (deduct a t)
else [h]@ (deduct a t)
;;

let rec pack l=
match l with
|[]-> []
|h::t -> [(expand [h] (frequency [h] l))]@ (pack (deduct [h] t))
;;
```

It is rather clear that this implementation is overkill, as I have to count the frequency of every element in the list, expand this and remove the identical elements from the list, then repeat the procedure. The algorithm complexity is about O(N*(N+N+N))=O(N^2) and would not work with large lists, even though it achieved the required purpose. I tried to read the official solution on the website, which says:

```
# let pack list =
    let rec aux current acc = function
      | [] -> []    (* Can only be reached if original list is empty *)
      | [x] -> (x :: current) :: acc
      | a :: (b :: _ as t) ->
         if a = b then aux (a :: current) acc t
         else aux [] ((a :: current) :: acc) t  in
    List.rev (aux [] [] list);;
val pack : 'a list -> 'a list list = <fun>
```

the code should be better as it is more concise and does the same thing. But I am confused with the use of "aux current acc" in the inside. It seems to me that the author has created a new function inside of the "pack" function and after some elaborate procedure was able to get the desired result using List.rev which reverses the list. What I do not understand is:

1) What is the point of using this, which makes the code very hard to read on first sight?

2) What is the benefit of using an accumulator and an auxiliary function inside of another function which takes 3 inputs? Did the author implicitly used tail recursion or something?

3) Is there anyway to modify the program so that it can pack *all* duplicates like my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are questions mostly of opinion rather than fact.

1) Your code is far harder to understand, in my opinion.

2a) It's very common to use auxiliary functions in OCaml and other functional languages. You should think of it more like nested curly braces in a C-like language rather than as something strange.

2b) Yes, the code is using tail recursion, which yours doesn't. You might try giving your code a list of (say) 200,000 distinct elements. Then try the same with the official solution. You might try determining the longest list of distinct values your code can handle, then try timing the two different implementations for that length.

2c) In order to write a tail-recursive function, it's sometimes necessary to reverse the result at the end. This just adds a linear cost, which is often not enough to notice.

3) I suspect your code doesn't solve the problem as given. If you're only supposed to compress *adjacent* elements, your code doesn't do this. If you wanted to do what your code does with the official solution you could sort the list beforehand. Or you could use a map or hashtable to keep counts.

Generally speaking, the official solution is far better than yours in many ways. Again, you're asking for an opinion and this is mine.

**Update**

The official solution uses an auxiliary function named `aux` that takes three parameters: the currently accumulated sublist (some number of repetitions of the same value), the currently accumulated result (in reverse order), and the remaining input to be processed.

The invariant is that all the values in the first parameter (named `current`) are the same as the head value of the unprocessed list. Initially this is true because `current` is empty.

The function looks at the first two elements of the unprocessed list. If they're the same, it adds the first of them to the beginning of `current` and continues with the tail of the list (all but the first). If they're different, it wants to start accumulating a different value in `current`. It does this by adding current (with the one extra value added to the front) to the accumulated result, then continuing to process the tail with an empty value for current. Note that both of these maintain the invariant.

Comment: Thanks for the objective opinion. Do you mind to explain the official solution? I totally agree my code is inferior for what your mentioned.

Comment: I also tried your suggestion. My "pack" caused a stackoverflow, and the official "pack" worked very well.

Comment: Excellent! Now try the timing! (I haven't tried this, but I did verify the stack overflow before sending my answer.)

Comment: I tried to google for it, but do not really know how to do it. I suspect my program is much slower as well. The official one looks like around O(N^2) as well, but should be much faster.

Comment: After thinking about this carefully and reading what you wrote 5 times, I finally got (why the official one works). Thanks!

Comment: The official solution is linear not quadratic.

Comment: I see. Now it is making sense as it only goes one step at a time.